# Find $x,y,z$ such that $6x+15y+20z=17$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Find $x,y,z$ such that:

$$ 6x+15y+20z=17 $$

I found this question in Hua Loo Keng's Number Theory under the Greatest Common Factor and Least Common Multiple section.

Comment: x,y,z integers? positive?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti, they cannot *all* be positive.

Comment: @lhf I know: they can also potatoes, as far as I can read

Comment: This one is easy: since $x=y=1$ and $z=-1$ gives a value of $1$, then…

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ Scale $\, 6 + 15 - 20 = 1\,$ by $\,17.\, $  See my answer in the linked dupe for how to do it simply by the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers of the form $6x+15y$ are exactly the multiples of $3=\gcd(6,15)$.

So, first solve $3t+20z=17$ and then solve $3t=6x+15y$ or $t=2x+5y$.

Actually, it is easier in this case to start at the other end.

The numbers of the form $15y+20z$ are exactly the multiples of $5=\gcd(15,20)$. So, first solve $6x+5u=17$ and then solve $5u=15y+20z$ or $u=3y+4z$.

The solution $x=2,u=1$ for $6x+5u=17$ stands out. So does the solution $y=-1, z=1$ for $u=3y+4z$.

Comment: Easier: scale $\, 6 + 15 - 21 = 1\ $ -- see the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Including answer of lhf,  I saw that $x\equiv 2(mod~5)$ or $x={2,7,12,17,\cdots}$

For each $x$ we get $u$ respectively as $u=1,-5,-11,-17,\cdots $

For each $u, y=-u, z=u$ , satisfy the equation except $u=y=1, z=-1$

So the final answer is $(x,y,z)=(5k+2,6k-1,1-6k)$ for $k=1,2,3,\cdots$ and one left is $(x,y,z)=(2,-1,1)$

Now it is finished.